# RCA tablet to VGA monitor

Tags: external-display

I have an Android RCA tablet that I need to connect to a VGA Monitor.  I have purchased a cable with a mini HDMI on one end and a VGA on the other end to fit both the tablet and the monitor but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to an answer, now that we've narrowed in on your needs:

A straight cable can't handle this. What you'll need is a converter. Per your comment question, [here's a well-reviewed one on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00879DM56) for pretty cheap that will do the job. You'll want to pair that with a female-HDMI to male-mini or micro-HDMI (make sure you're sure which you have) adapter, which are usually less than a dollar, and a standard, run-of-the-mill VGA cable, and you SHOULD be good to go.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why it came with a USB also!
After, adjusted HDMI to 720 60hz, works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have the 7" Voyager. It does not have a mini-HDMI port, just a micro USB. So with that being said, I don't think it's possible.